# Spring boot and Security Integration test with EntityManager

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data

I want to test my spring application. It requires authentication, so I create an user object and persist it in `@Before` method. But i can not do authentication because, as i think, `init()` method is executed in another session.

`IntegrationTest` class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Transactional
public class IntegrationTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @LocalServerPort
    int port;

    private String URL;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("testUser");
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("test"));
        user.setEmail("test@test.com");
        user.setEnabled(true);
        entityManager.persist(user);
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();

        RestAssured.port = port;

        URL = "http://localhost:" + String.valueOf(port) + "/users/user";
    }

    @Test
    public void givenNotAuthenticatedUser_whenLoggingIn_thenCorrect() {
        final RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().auth().basic("testUser", "test");

        request.when().get(URL).then().assertThat().statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

But if I use my `userRepository` and call

```
userRepository.save(user);
```

instead of

```
entityManager.persist(user);
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.clear();
```

everything works fine. I also have to remove `@Transactional` annotation.

Firstly I thought it was because, there was no commit - I saw that there is no changes in the user table. How to force `EntityManager` to commit data?

How to use `EntityManager` in test? And why `UserRepository` does work well?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testing-tx):

> By default, the framework will create and roll back a transaction for each test.

You can override it using `@Commit` on your test class and put `TestTransaction.end()` after `entityManager.clear()`.

Now the test works ok but I still can not understand why and how `UserRepository` works without commiting the transaction.

Comment: Why downvote? I have three parts in my question and this is the answer to "How to force EntityManager to commit data?".